# How do we know that grammar is a thing?

Tags: ontology, linguistics

I mean, is there a thought experiment that shows its ontological validity?

Could it concievably, based on the data that we have, be merely an epiphenomenon of syntax and semantics?

Comment: What a good and interesting subject! Is there any chance you might be able to tell us a little more about what sort of answer you might be expecting? (Also: what have you found out so far?)

Comment: Grammar epiphenomenal were if, the lack of sentence this grammaticality evident of would how be? Induced by meaning and syntax, the accepted orderings of the words in a sentence is, do you think?

Comment: Is there anyone who argues that grammar is an ontic entity?

Comment: @MichaelDorfman: Of course it's an "ontic entity". It's something you can describe mathematically with a parser. It's a mathematical structure, like addition.

Comment: @RonMaimon: Many philosophers are not mathematical Platonists, and would argue that mathematical structures require no ontological commitment.

Comment: @MichaelDorfman: I don't believe in "ontology" really, as I'm a positivist. So I should have said "it's as real as I am, which is not very".

Answer (score 7):

Isn't an epiphenomenon a thing?  Is it really useful to say that--forgive the overly-used example--"air pressure doesn't exist" because it is an epiphenomenon of the statistical properties of air molecules?  Indeed, if you follow this sort of logic to its most reductionistic extremes, you start to conclude that *nothing is a thing* except for those very most fundamental forces and logical constructs, the former of which, at least, we probably haven't fully discovered yet.  In order to avoid a complete inability to converse, you then have to invent a new word for "thing" (entity, object, whatever) that means basically what the old "thing" meant before you destroyed it.  This is perhaps an interesting exercise, but ultimately an unproductive one.

You could ask instead: *is there a difference in kind, in some important way, between grammar and the otherwise undirected interplay of syntax and semantics*?  Considerable difficulty in answering this question arises because grammar is not something that we defined mathematically and then sought to understand, but rather is something that we observed people using.  One way to proceed is to ask whether our brains are specialized for grammar in a way that is separable from syntax and semantics.  If yes, then in *some* sense it is at least an interesting enough epiphenomenon to be worth talking about in its own right.

And, in fact, there is moderately good evidence that this is the case.  Damage to [Wernicke's area](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wernicke%27s_area) causes syntactically and grammatically mostly-correct production of semantic nonsense.  Thus, our brains compute semantics separately from syntax and grammar.  In contrast, modest damage to [Broca's area](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broca%27s_area) can cause retention many elements of correct syntax, but with muddled grammar--strange choices of word order, [difficulty in understanding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aphasiology) certain grammatically valid word orders, and so on.  Although this is less clear than the result for Wernicke's area (severe damage can result in the loss of the ability to speak, or the retention of the ability to only speak a handful of words, and the distinction between syntax and grammar is not all that crisply defined anyway), we can provisionally say that there are grammar specializations distinct from rudimentary syntax and the full richness of semantics.

Thus, yes, grammar is a thing.  Our brains think so, at least.

Comment: Bravo! Cognitive science, reductionism, maths.

Answer (score 1):

There is the real experiment of raising children.  If we observe children learning language we see two very odd things:

1) They err on the side of assuming grammar is more consistent and rigid than it is.  They may well know the word 'taught', and then, when the pattern of ordinary past tense formation 'clicks' for them as a pattern, temporarily start using the word 'teached', which they have never heard or used up until that time.

2) When they get grammar wrong, it tends to be wrong in a way that would be correct in another language, and they consistently make the same mistake several times.  They are temporarily sure that, for instance, we should consistently mark all of our infinitives, or that we should use gerunds freely in place of infinitives.  Again, this is not from experience -- American children don't likely have a Gaelic or German exemplar who puts in too many 'to's or too many 'ing's.  They learn that those patterns are wrong, but there is no good evidence why they should have dreamed up the wrong pattern to begin with, instead of just assuming there is no pattern, and learning each instance.  In fact, as with 'teached' and 'catched' they already have enough instances in exerience to prove the pattern wrong, and they try it out anyway.

These two experiences lead us to presume that grammar is not just accidental, since it is not entirely learned, but is established by searching a specific predetermined space of options.